# Any simple implementations of JColorChooser?

Tags: java, applet

I'm in the process of applet development in which I need a simple 16 item colour chooser.  Has anyone implemented something simple like this before? Any of the examples I have come across are not the most aesthetically pleasing or user friendly....

As always, help is greatly appreciated...

Cheers,

Slotishtype

Answer (score 2):

Lot of choice, here:

http://storybook.intertec.ch/joomla/index.php/developers/104-clever-color-chooser-for-java-swing

http://sites.google.com/site/nicestep/

http://uic.sourceforge.net/

And also copyrighted solutions here:

http://www.java2s.com/Product/Java/Swing/Color-Chooser.htm